# With Knockout JS how to render JavaScript code dynamically using template binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-templating

I am building a HTML form dynamically using Knockout template binding. Each form definition has its own set of JavaScript functions used for custom validation.

How do I render java script code (functions) to the page so they can be invoked during validation? The reason why JavaScript code is inserted dynamically is because they are user defined.

The end result should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function a() {};  // inserted dynamically
   function b() {}:  // inserted dynamically
   ...
</script>
```

When the custom validation makes use of only one JavaScript function there is "no problem" - I can just use the eval() command to execute it. However when then function needs to make reference to another function then things become bit  more complex. I've got two problems here:

1. I should not be using the eval() command since it is slow and unsafe.
2. When a function needs to reference another function even the eval() option wont' help me.

So I thought if could render all JavaScript functions dynamically inside a script tag and then I could reference the functions using [Window].[functionName] instead of using the eval() command.

Let me stress the point that these JavaScript functions are not all located in one separate file. They are scattered in a complex JSON object built by the server which represents the form definition which will drive the loading of the dynamic form. There are many different form definitions.

Comment: Why not just use knockout.validation and write custom rules for each field on your form? Adding dynamic JavaScript to elements seems a bit of an antipattern with knockout.js.

Comment: Have a look at the Knockout documentation for components with AMD loaders.  The component syntax allows you to factor your HTML and view model out into separate modules that can be dynamically loaded from require.js.

Comment: @CameronTinker : This app uses the Knockout.js framework but we also make use of Kendo UI. For validation, instead of KO validation, we're using Kendo UI validator and Kendo UI tooltip which works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create script tag in form template.
2. Concatenate JavaScript functions from JSON object and store them in string.
3. Using JQuery insert variable containing JavaScript functions into script tag.